# Suggestions for linux/unbuntu with access to usb port

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb

I need to get a linux or ubuntu (the former preferably) on windows10 and have it have access to the usb port. Anyone have suggestions on where I should start?

Comment: welcome to superuser: what research have you done already:eg: https://askubuntu.com/questions "how to ......."

Comment: A good area to start is the  Ubuntu site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi Do you wish to dual boot, Wubi, etc all should provide access to usb’s

Answer (score 0):

If you boot into (say) Ubuntu running from a USB drive then you will have instant access to the other USB ports by default in a file-manager window.

But if you're trying to see the files on the actual USB which is already running the Ubuntu install you can:

- Use `df -h` to find out the path of your USB drive *dev* directory (eg. /dev/sda1).
- Create a mounted directory there with : `cd && mkdir temp_usb`
- Mount a new USB device into the that new directory with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 temp_usb`

You will then be able to browse to temp_usb.

You can also use `lsusb | more` to see what's connected to the USB ports which might help you troubleshooting.

Comment: Was this any use to you?